# R: Removing text from column 1 in a list

Tags: r

[FASTA file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh6FF.png)

I have a fasta file with 100 sequences and I would like to remove everything else than the species name marked in red. There are 100 entries and there's a lot of different species names further down the list.

I've tried:

```
s1 <- sapply(strsplit(fasta.file$Header, split=' ', fixed=TRUE), function(x) (x[2]))
[1] "Acossus" ...

s2 <- sapply(strsplit(fasta.file$Header, split=' ', fixed=TRUE), function(x) (x[3]))
[1] "populi" ...
```

But this doesn't really solve my problem, or I don't see how it does. I'm really new to R. I'd appreciate every help. Thank you!

edit:

as requested:

[dput(head(fasta.file)) results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYE3P.png)

and here is a piece the results:

```
        > dput(head(fasta.file))
    structure(list(Header = c("KT147837.1 Acossus populi voucher HLC-20342 cytochrome oxidase subunit 1 (COI) gene, partial cds; mitochondrial", 
    "GU092174.1 Acossus centerensis voucher BIOUG<CAN>:Moth4503.03 cytochrome oxidase subunit 1 (COI) gene, partial cds; mitochondrial", 
    "KF492042.1 Prionoxystus sp. BOLD:AAY7397 voucher CWM-94-0234 cytochrome oxidase subunit 1 (COI) gene, partial cds; mitochondrial", 
    "JQ604298.1 Ceromacra sp. Poole01 cytochrome oxidase subunit 1 (COI) gene, partial cds; mitochondrial"
    ), Sequence = c("AATAGTAGGAACTTCTCTAAGTTTATTAATTCGAGCTGAATTAGGAAATCCAGGGTCCCTAATTGGGAATGACCAAATTTATAATACTATTGTTACAGCTCATGCTTTCATCATAATTTTTTTCATAGTAATACCAATCATAATTGGAGGATTTGGAAATTGATTAGTACCACTAATATTAGGAGCCCCCGATATAGCTTTCCCACGAATAAACAATATAAGATTTTGACTATTACCCCCATCCCTAACCCTTTTAATTTCTAGAAGTATTGTTGAAAATGGAGCTGGCACAGGATGAACTGTTTACCCCCCTTTATCATCTAATATTGCTCATAGAGGAAGATCAGTTGATTTAGCAATTTTCTCTTTACATTTAGCTGGTATTTCATCAATTTTAGGAGCTATTAATTTCATTACAACAATTATTAATATACGACCTAATAACATATCATTTGATCAAATACCACTATTTATTTGAGCTGTTGGAATTACTACTTTACTACTACTTCTTTCACTTCCAGTTTTAGCTGGTGCAATTACTATATTATTAACAGATCGAAATTTAAATACATCATTTTTTGACCCTGCAGGAG", 
    "AACATTATATTTTATTTTTGGTATTTGATCTGGAATAGTGGGAACTTCTCTAAGTTTATTAATTCGAACTGAATTAGGAAACCCAGGATCTCTAATTGGGAATGATCAAATTTATAATACTATTGTTACAGCTCATGCTTTCATTATAATTTTTTTCATAGTAATACCAATTATAATTGGAGGATTTGGAAATTGATTAGTGCCTCTAATATTAGGAGCCCCTGATATAGCTTTCCCACGGATAAACAACATAAGATTTTGATTATTACCCCCATCATTAACCCTTTTAATTTCTAGAAGTATTATTGAAAATGGAGCCGGCACAGGATGAACTGTCTATCCCCCTTTATCATCTAATATTTCCCACGGAGGAAGATCAGTTGATTTAACGATTTTCTCCTTACATTTAGCTGGTATTTCATCAATTTTAGGAGCTATTAATTTCATTACAACAATTATTAATATACGACCTAATAATATATCATTTGATCAAATACCATTATTTGTTTGAGCTGTTGGAATTACTGCTTTACTACTTCTGCTTTCATTACCCGTTTTAGCTGGAGCAATTACTATATTATTAACAGACCGAAATTTAAATACATCATTTTTTGACCCTGCAGGAGGAGGAGANCCTATTTTATATCAACATTTATTT", 
    "AACATTATATTTCATTTTTGGTATTTGATCTGGAATAGTGGGAACTTCTTTAAGTTTATTAATTCGAGCTGAATTAGGAAATCCAGGATCTCTAATTGGAAACGATCAAATTTATAATACTATTGTTACAGCTCATGCTTTTATTATAATTTTTTTTATGGTAATACCAATTATAATTGGAGGATTTGGAAATTGATTAGTACCATTAATACTAGGAGCTCCTGACATAGCTTTCCCCCGAATAAATAATATAAGATTTTGATTATTACCCCCCTCTTTAACTCTTCTTCTTTCTAGAAGTATCGTTGAAAATGGAGCTGGCACAGGATGAACTGTTTACCCCCCTTTATCATCAAATATCGCTCATGGAGGAAGATCAATTGATTTAGCAATCTTCTCTTTACATTTAGCTGGTATTTCATCAATCTTAGGGGCCATTAACTTCATTACAACGATCATTAATATACGACCTAATAACATATCATTTGATCAAATACCTTTATTTGTTTGAGCTGTTGGAATTACCGTCTTATTACTTTTACTTTCTCTACCAGTTCTAACTGGAGCAATTACTATGTTATTAACAGATCGAAATTTAAATACATCATTTTTTGATCCTGCAGGAGGGGGAGACCCTATTTTATACCAACATTTATTT", 
    "AACTTTATATTTTATTTTTGGAATTTGAGCAGGAATAGTAGGAACTTCTTTAAGTTTATTAATTCGAGCTGAACTAGGAAATCCTGGTTCTCTTATTGGAGATGATCAAATTTATAATACTATTGTTACAGCTCATGCTTTTATTATAATTTTTTTTATAGTTATACCTATTATAATTGGAGGATTTGGAAATTGATTAGTACCTTTAATATTAGGAGCCCCAGATATAGCTTTCCCCCGAATAAATAATATAAGTTTTTGATTATTACCCCCTTCACTAACTCTTTTAATTTCTAGAAGAATTGTAGAAAATGGAGCAGGTACAGGATGAACAGTTTACCCCCCACTTTCATCTAATATTGCTCATGGAGGTAGATCAGTTGATTTAGCTATTTTTTCATTACATTTAGCTGGTATTTCATCAATTTTAGGAGCAATTAATTTTATTACAACAATTATTAATATACGATTAAATAATTTATCATTTGATCAAATACCCCTCTTTATTTGAGCTGTAGGAATTACTGCATTTCTTTTACTTTTATCATTACCTGTATTAGCTGGAGCAATTACTATACTTTTAACAGATCGAAATTTAAATACATCATTTTTTGATCCAGCAGGAGGAGGAGATCCAATTCNNTATCAACATTTATTT"
    )), .Names = c("Header", "Sequence"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("Fasta", 
    "data.frame"))
>
```

Comment: Could you provide a piece of this dataset? Maybe you can try x[2:3], but it's hard to say without the data.

Comment: Please use dput(head(fasta.file)) and paste the results to your post so that we have some data to work with.

Comment: @LenkaVraná I've included a screenshot of the dataset if that's what you mean.

Comment: I meant the dataset, not the screenshot of the dataset. Something that we can copy and put directly into R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly and the names are always on second and third position in the Header column, then you can get those names as

```
s1 <- lapply(fasta.file$Header, function(x) paste(strsplit(x, split='\\s+')[[1]][2:3], collapse = ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the location of species name with `regexpr`

```
regexpr(".1",fasta.file$Header)[1]+3
regexpr("voucher",fasta.file$Header)[1]-2
```

Which means it is between `.1` and `voucher`.

Then remove it with `sub`

```
sub(substr(fasta.file$Header,regexpr(".1",fasta.file$Header)[1]+3,regexpr("voucher",fasta.file$Header)[1]-2),"",fasta.file$Header)
```

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong but I got this warning when I sourced the code.

Warning message:
In sub(substr(fasta.file$Header, regexpr(".1", fasta.file$Header)[1] +  :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` package lets you "pipe" things from top to bottom, 
with `%>%`, feels more natural than nested functions.

```
library(dplyr) 
fa$Header %>% 
        gsub(pattern="^\\S+\\s", replacement="", perl=TRUE) %>%
        gsub(pattern="\\s.+$", replacement="", perl=TRUE)
```

Result:

```
[1] "Acossus"      "Acossus"      "Prionoxystus" "Ceromacra"
```

Here I've removed all nonwhitespace chars from the beginning of the string to first whitespace.

In a second `gsub()`, then deleted everything from  first whitespace to end of string. This preserves only the seond word.

This does not work if you have Species consisting of two parts, e.g. "mus musculus".